# Execute ruby subprocess which requires interactive input

Tags: ruby, input, subprocess

I need to start a subprocess from ruby, that takes over then returns control.
This subprocess needs interactive input from the user, so it's io should be tied to stdin stdout and stderr. Further it requests for input changes depending on the circumstances.

An example of a program like that is TeX, which I would start on a file but during the process TeX may encounter a user error which it has to query the user how to fix.

Essentially I am looking for a reentrant version of exec.

PS

For those who cannot read carefully let me reiterate.

**This subprocess needs interactive input from the user**

That means that if the ruby program runs in a tty,  that its output goes to the tty not the Ruby program and its input comes from the tty, not the Ruby program.

In other words:
**Essentially I am looking for a reentrant version of exec.**

I use TeX as an example so let me show you an example. I found a sample piece of TeX on the at [Sample Tex](http://www.math.wisc.edu/computing/tex/sample.html) . I intend to put an error in but it seems I don't have to it chokes on my system. Save it in sample1.tex, sample2.tex, sample3.tex.

Now I would like to run this bit of ruby code:

```
files=["sample1.tex","sample2.tex","sample3.tex"]
files.each{|file|
     # It is really a latex command.
     commmand_that_I_am_looking_for("latex #{file}")
 }
```

When I run this code I should see in the terminal, three times a bunch of stuff:

*Generic information about the latex program, progress in processing etc.*

```
! LaTeX Error: File `html.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
```

Where upon each of the three times the program waits for the user to type something.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing what do you wish to achieve. Would you like to control interactive input/output of a subprocess programatically ? If you do, then there is a standard PTY module for such tasks. See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html

Comment: I'm not getting how this is tricky. How does the obvious [`Kernel::system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) not do what you want?  It runs the command you pass it in a subshell which inherits the stdin/stdout/stderr of your ruby process; it blocks waiting for the subprocess to exit.

Answer (score 1):

You can pair `fork` with `exec`:

```rb
Process.fork { exec('./somescript') }
Process.wait
```

The `Process.wait` ensures that you wait for the subprocess to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby standard library has a special command for your needs. It is called [`open3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3). Here is an example from its docs:

```
Open3.popen3("pwd", :chdir=>"/") {|stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  p stdout.read.chomp #=> "/"
}
```

Comment: Explain to me what kind of user input your sample program "pwd" takes?

Comment: @Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog Almost everyone here is trying to help others and learn from each other. Calling someone dumb is not constructive. Explaining how and why you think they are wrong is. Try to be polite, not everyone sees what you see, and no one owes you their time or attention.